# How to invoke generic lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, lambda, compilation, invoke

```
private void ExecuteCommand(Expression<Func<bool>> command)
{
    bool success = command.Compile().Invoke();
}

private void Test()
{
    ExecuteCommand(() => _gc.ChargeCancellation(""));
}
```

With this code, I got a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Where did you get a NullReferenceExecption?   What is _gc?

Comment: Is `_gc` being initialized in some code you didn't post?

Comment: ah the exception was thrown by _gc internally ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look through the stack trace or add a breakpoint at this line:

```
ExecuteCommand(() => _gc.ChargeCancellation(""));
```

Given the information you have posted there's no chance of anybody in this community really helping you beyond generic comments.

Answer (score 3):

Is `_gc` null by any chance? Or perhaps `ChargeCancellation` itself is throwing the exception? It should work fine otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Since you show no code to initialize `_gc`, my guess is that is where your NullReferenceException is happening.

Either that or something inside `_gc.ChargeCancellation(`) is throwing the Exception.

It might help if you included the full text of the Exception so we knew exactly where the Exception was being thrown.